# Generic java.util.function.Function for Grouping as per input

Tags: java, java-stream

I have class Foo which has some field and I want to group them to `Map<Object,List<Foo>>` by fields as follow:

```
class Foo {
    private String cassette;
    private List<String> organ; //not able to group on List<String>
    private LocalDate date;
    //getter setter toString
}

enum Group{
    CASSETTE,
    ORGAN,
    DATE
}
```

I have a switch case for Grouping by `java.util.function.Function` for `Collectors.groupingBy()` as follow:

```
Function<Foo, Object> keyCriteria;

Group groupBy = Group.values()[1];//ordinal
switch (groupBy) {
case CASSETTE:
    keyCriteria = p -> p.getCassette();
    break;
case DATE:
    keyCriteria = p -> p.getDate();
    break;
case ORGAN:
    keyCriteria = p -> p.getOrgan(); //facing problem while grouping with List<String>
    break;
default:
    keyCriteria = p -> p.getCassette();
}

Map<Object, List<Foo>> mapByCriteria = fooList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(keyCriteria));
System.out.println(mapByCriteria);
```

Everything works fine except `case ORGAN:`

Result getting:

> {[Lung, Liver]=[Foo [cassette=1A, organ=[Lung, Liver],
>   date=2020-01-13]], [Liver]=[Foo [cassette=2A, organ=[Liver],
>   date=2020-01-15]]}

Expected result:

> {Liver=[Foo [cassette=1A, organ=[Lung, Liver], date=2020-01-13], Foo
>   [cassette=2A, organ=[Liver], date=2020-01-15]], Lung=[Foo
>   [cassette=1A, organ=[Lung, Liver], date=2020-01-13]]}

Achieved expected result by work around following:

```
Map<Object, List<Foo>> collect = fooList.stream()
                .flatMap(f -> f.getOrgan().stream().map(o -> new SimpleEntry<>(o, f))).collect(Collectors
                        .groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
```

I'm looking for a `switch` case and `Generic` solution.

Comment: You want to group by all values in the List? or just a specific value?

Comment: are you expecting `Mp<String, List<Foo>>` or `Map<Object, List<Foo>>` or in the case of orange, the result should be `Map<List<String>, List<Foo>>`

Comment: When you pass a `Function<Foo, Object>` to `groupingBy`, you can’t get a `Map<String, List<Foo>>` as result type. This code shouldn’t even pass the compiler.

Comment: @Holger A String is an Object. Every class is a subclass of Object. The compiler allows it, try it on your IDE and suggest me a solution

Comment: @YCF_L I'm expecting `Map<String, List<Foo>>` or `Map<Object, List<Foo>>` and not `Map<List<String>, List<Foo>>`

Comment: You function *returns* `Object` the result map *expects* `String` and not every object is a string, hence, my IDE rejects your code as expected. Since `getOrgan()` returns a `List`, it should be obvious that something is wrong when this `List` gets stored as an alleged `String` key into your map. [ideone confirms it](https://ideone.com/vFVOfA)…

Comment: Okay make it to `Object` but the problem is with Grouping, I don't have a problem whether it is `String` or `Object` @Holger. Also edited my question since it is creating problem

Comment: The ORGAN case is fundamentally different because it is a many-to-many relationship, whereas the others are one-to-many. A direct `groupingBy` cannot work when you want each object to possibly appear in multiple groups. Your "workaround" (which is the answer to a question you posted here yesterday) is not a workaround, it is just the correct way to do this. It is different to the other cases because it solves a different problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not handle fundamentally different operations, like a plain mapping and a flattening, with the same code. You have to handle the special case specially:

```
public static Map<String, List<Foo>> mapByCriteria(List<Foo> fooList, Group criteria) {
    Function<Foo, String> simpleKeyCriteria;
    switch(criteria) {
        case CASSETTE: simpleKeyCriteria = Foo::getCassette; break;
        case DATE: simpleKeyCriteria = p -> p.getDate().toString(); break;
        case ORGAN:
            return fooList.stream()
                .flatMap(foo -> foo.getOrgan().stream()
                    .map(organ -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(organ, foo)))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
                    Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
        default:
            throw new AssertionError(criteria);
    }
    return fooList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(simpleKeyCriteria));
}
```

In principle, it would possible to share more common operations, by splitting the stream statement into parts, but it would produce even more code while the only common code is `fooList.stream()`. So in this specific case, this is no win. But for completeness:

```
public static Map<String, List<Foo>> mapByCriteria(List<Foo> fooList, Group criteria) {
    Stream<Foo> stream = fooList.stream(); // imagine more chained common operations
    Function<Foo, String> simpleKeyCriteria = null;
    Collector<Foo, ?, Map<String, List<Foo>>> collector = null;
    switch(criteria) {
        case CASSETTE: simpleKeyCriteria = Foo::getCassette; break;
        case DATE: simpleKeyCriteria = p -> p.getDate().toString(); break;
        case ORGAN: collector = Collectors.flatMapping(
            foo -> foo.getOrgan().stream()
                .map(organ -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(organ, foo)),
            Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
                Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
        default:
            throw new AssertionError(criteria);
    }
    if(collector == null) collector = Collectors.groupingBy(simpleKeyCriteria);
    return stream.collect(collector);
}
```

This bears absolutely no code duplication, but as demonstrated, is not necessarily a win over accepting small code duplication.

Comment: Thanks @Holger what I was achieving is to avoid duplication of code for the one who doesn't actually identical